# Why can't I turn on Wi-Fi on the Waydroid emulator?

Tags: linux, android-emulator, emulators

I just installed the Android emulator called Waydroid on Ubuntu 22.04. Almost everything seems to work as expected, except that I'm completely unable to turn on Wi-Fi usage. Whenever I toggle Wi-Fi on in the settings, the toggle goes to "On" but it doesn't actually turn on. If I leave that page in the settings, and return, it resets to Off. Any help?

Comment: The applications which run an emulation or a virtualized service typically won't give you access to the network interfaces of the host system. They usually create their own virtual network interface and make their app/service rely on that for network access. Try listing network interfaces in your host (Ubuntu). You'd most likely find waydroid0 or something which is responsible for providing network access to the emulator. Within the emulator you'd probably have eth0 or something else named ethernet interface. It is through that interface the emulator can talk to the host.

Comment: ...Wi-fi settings of Android in your emulator is as useless as the Wi-Fi settings in Android emulator offered by Google. IMO, It is there because removing it from the Settings app's code is not worth it.